# Symfony2 .htaccess should also check if the requested file exists in a subdirectory within web and serve it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I want to extend the following .htaccess rewriteCond to also check if the requested file exists within a subfolder in web (and serve it, not redirect - but serve the file)

```
# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f    
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

for example I have the following files in sub-directories within Web folder of symfony project

```
static/contact.php
static/wiki/countries.php
```

the request URLs look like this

```
localhost/symfony/web/contact.php (www.domain.com/contact.php)
localhost/symfony/web/wiki/countries.php (www.domain.com/wiki/countries.php)
```

i do not want to redirect, just want to serve the contents.

Let me elaborate a little further.

I am currently in the process of upgrading an old php project to symfony2 framework.

The old project has the following URL structure for static pages

```
www.domain.com/faq.php
www.domain.com/contact.php
www.domain.com/wiki/countries.php
```

Now in order for this to work as it is - I have to copy the static page and the wiki folder in the WEB folder of the new symfony2 project. Which is fine and the above given Rule / conditions would work and the above URLs would work.

But I do not want to copy the static pages into WEB as it will clutter the WEB folder, and i want to keep it clean - So I moved the static pages to a sub folder within WEB folder called static. Now the above URLs do not work, and throw a page not found error coz all the pages are within web/static folder. so with the current Rule / cond the URLs will have to be changed to

```
www.domain.com/static/faq.php
www.domain.com/static/contact.php
www.domain.com/static/wiki/countries.php
```

Is there a way where I can keep the previous URL structure and keep the static pages within a sub folder in web? one way which i can think of is that to have a cond and rule in .htaccesss file within WEB folder to also check for requesting files within static folder and if it is found, then serve them (not redirect)

thanks for you time and help, much appreciated.

Comment: your existing rules should work fine for a PHP file in a subdirectory as well.

Comment: No, I want www.domain.com/contact.php to open - home/symfony/web/static/contact.php ... and ... www.domain.com/wiki/countries.php to open - home/symfony/web/static/wiki/countries.php - this is an example to understand - want a generic rule so that the sub dirs are also considered - the rules stated in the question - only check for files in web folder - so if i move the contact.php from static to web then it will work ... but that is what i want to avoid.

Comment: would this even make sense to do? as there are many static pages, I can't change the URL coz they are indexed by google changing the URL would mean re-indexing and lose of alot of effort.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said - your existing rules check for the existence of the file, subdirectory or not, and if it exists it does nothing except load the file. The `-` tells it to ignore if matched and the `[L]` says to not process any additional rules.